# get object properties from posix signal handler in C++

Tags: c++, linux, signals, posix

I'm trying to get a signal handler to work in C++ and can't figure out how to make use of some class properties.

The signal handler triggers when a SIGIO signal is received and I need to check if it's for the right socket.

All I need to do is to be able to access the private `socket_` and the public `received()`.

```
namespace sigh {

 template<typename SomeType>
 class WorkWithSignals
 {
 public:
   void received( unsigned char* data, size_t len, unsigned int from );

 private:
   static void sigio_handler ( int sig, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* empty );
   int socket_;
 };

 extern "C" {
   void sigio_handler ( int sig, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* empty ) {
      if (siginfo->si_fd == ***socket_*** )
        ***received*** ();
   }
 }

}
```

Among other things I tried defining a static struct variable before the definition of the `sigio_handler`, fill it in in the class constructor defined after `sigio_handler`, but the `sigio_handler` complained that it wasn't in scope.

Any pointers?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but signal handlers don't have to be `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access member variable from static method (there is just no object). You could make your `socket_` a static variable too, and reference it by `WorkWithSignals<...>::socket_`.

Answer (score 1):

The signal handler is a static method so it is not bound to any instance of your class.

The sigaction man page contains the paragraph (relating to the siginfo_t parameter):

```
   * SIGPOLL/SIGIO fills in si_band and si_fd.  The si_band event is a bit
     mask containing the same values as are filled in the revents field by
     poll(2).  The si_fd field indicates the file descriptor for which the
     I/O event occurred.
```

Assuming that you want to continue with your current signal based design (poll() may be easier), I would suggest a static map of file descriptors to instances of your WorkWithSignals class.

Then in the static signal handler, lookup the instance related to the given file descriptor (your socket_ field) and then call a non-static method to do the needed work with the specific object.

to the decl of WorkWithSignals add

```
static std::map<int, WorkWithSignals*> object_registry_;
```

and the needed def in the source file. Manage membership in the map by adding to the map before registering the signal handler and removing from the map before destroying the object. Then:

```
   void sigio_handler ( int sig, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* empty ) {
      std::map<int, WorkWithSignals*>::iterator it = object_registry_.find(siginfo->si_fd);
      if(it == object_registry_.end())
          // handle error case
          assert(false);

      // Check that si_band is masked with the read flag as in the poll() call (look for revents)
      WorkWithSignals* obj = it->second;
      obj->received();
   }
```